# Drupal deployment of content modern techniques

Tags: php, drupal, deployment, module, content-management-system

I would like to know if there are moderns techniques for deployment content in drupal 7.

I know there is a module named [deployment](https://drupal.org/project/deploy), but it seems kinda unestable.

I've also know that with features you can export content using node-export, but i would like to limit features to settings, content types, etc...

My site right know it's on a development server, it has panels, webforms, and tons and tons of different dependency modules. And as far i can think i guess that the only way to export the content it's going to be with backup and migrate.

There is a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Deployments with Drupal have always been a constant struggle with our team. We use a combination of features and node-export. It seems to work the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About deployment in Drupal, you need to clearly differentiate between:

1. **Code**: Drupal core, contrib modules, your own modules, patches, themes, translations.
2. **Content**: everything that is stored inside nodes, content types and entities. Always in the DB.
3. **Configuration** *(here comes the problems...)* : everything not included in 1) or 2):

   - site global variables
   - definition of content types, bundles and entities
   - definition of fields
   - views
   - panels
   - forms
   - blocks
   - menus
   - vocabularies
   - permissions
   - rules
   - ...

All this configuration information is now dispersed in the database in D7, and it is really a nightmare to manage, deploy and maintain it. Until the arrival of D8 (that will provide a new configuration Management System precisely to solve this problem), you will need to use modules like Features and Strongarm to fight with this. The process is not simple and require to split precisely the functionality of your site, looking for *self-contained* parts of code & configuration that represents user-cases. If not, you will find a lot of problems with dependencies between features.

Deploying code and content is much easier. Use Drush make and, if needed, installation profiles and Features. For content, an easy solution is Backup & Migrate module.

You can find a recent and extensive comparative of Deployment modules in Drupal 7 here:

https://drupal.org/node/980186

Comment: Oh nice, this will help alot. Yeah, that's why i wasn't able to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it **once** use normal deploying methods. Transfer files, copy database and change your settings.php file as also as other files you may have edit (robots.txt, .htaccess etc) except if you have the same server configuration for each site.

If you want to do it on **rare times**, eg once per year use [backup & migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and its complementary modules.

Finally if you want to deploy between different environments of the site **on a regular basis** (eg when there are security updates) use [Drush](http://drush.ws/) and drush aliases. See [Using drush to synchronize and deploy sites](https://drupal.org/node/670460) for more details.